# What api to use instead of TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory for relaying tokens to microservice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-security

I am currently following an example to forward jwt tokens from a spring gateway service to a backend microservice.
The api-gateway example uses `org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.gateway.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory` to relay token to backend microservice but it is now deprecated.

It comes from this depenendency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The following is the existing code that uses the deprecated api:

```
public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("car-service", r -> r.path("/cars")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(filterFactory.apply()))
                        .uri("lb://car-service"))
                .build();
```

What is the new api to use?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't delete it so I will answer my own question.
I changed my spring boot version to following:

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.3</version>
 <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and I was already referencing this dependency also:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

and referenced this import:
 `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory;`